# How to make flat design like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: Flat design]

How to make flat design like this? 
I want to make from my photos

Comment: The image you posted is very much a digital drawing, not a photo with applied effects. That being said, I'm preparing an answer with some hints how to _approximate_ this.

Comment: You should post what you've attempted to do to create this in your question in order to show that you've put effort into solving it. You're likely to get better answers if that is the case

Comment: You draw it, it's not an "effect" applied to a photo.

Answer (score 2):

Since the image is symmetrical, we'll create only one half of the image. Place your reference picture as the base layer and hide its one half by placing a white layer over it, like the image below,,

[image: half face]

Now make a new layer (we will call this layer A) over the base layer (that is half face of yours). Trace your face's outline with pen tool, don't be perfect, a basic shape of the skull would work, do not trace hair as those might be assymetrical. Close the path and make selection with it. fill it with desired color.

Now, duplicate layer A and flip it horizontally to have a full basic shape of the face. Merge both these layers and hide the resulting layer so that u can see your real face and trace other features.

Make another new layer and follow the same procedure (making half, duplicate, flip and merge) to make eyes, nose, mouth etc.

Hide the layers of these features as well. Delete white layer to see full face of yours. Make a new layer and trace the hair.

the important thing is distinctive features, like for the image you provided as example, its beard, glasses and hairstyle.