# Web design trend - Sketched characters animation

Tags: style-identification, trends

Can someone tell me what are those? I see them quite often now in several different applications.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't take the sarcastic humor in the comments personally. It's just because we've heard this question so many times. For example: [1](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/129740/84899),  [2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/43210/84899), [3](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17350/84899), [4](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/114409/84899), [5](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/50437/84899), [6](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/68317/84899). To me these drawings don't have similar *style*, but similar *media*: simplistic vector drawing.

Answer (score 3):

Not everything has a "name".

These are merely illustrations, probably vector in nature, using a minimalist tone.

Comment: You're supposed to answer "Flat design" 

Comment: you're supposed to flag as dupe - I'll find the other question :)

Comment: Thanks for telling me how this site works `:)` I'm new around here and don't know all the procedures. (and it's only a dupe if you choose to maybe identify it as "flat" ... I don't.)

Comment: I call it "lazy design".

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the [Corporate Memphis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_Memphis) style